# Cannot access get.rvm.io

Tags: dns, debian, rvm, ping

I need to install rvm on my web server.
I'm getting

```
Couldn't resolve host 'get.rvm.io'
```

If I do `ping get.rvm.io`, I'm getting  weird results. It says `unknown host get.rvm.io` one time and then it can ping next time:

```
root@masper:~# ping get.rvm.io
ping: unknown host get.rvm.io
root@masper:~# ping get.rvm.io
PING get.rvm.io (97.107.133.48) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=95.1 ms
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=95.5 ms
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=3 ttl=51 time=95.7 ms
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=4 ttl=51 time=95.2 ms
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=5 ttl=51 time=94.7 ms
^C
--- get.rvm.io ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 94.718/95.269/95.781/0.529 ms
root@masper:~# ping get.rvm.io
ping: unknown host get.rvm.io
root@masper:~# ping get.rvm.io
ping: unknown host get.rvm.io
root@masper:~# ping get.rvm.io
PING get.rvm.io (97.107.133.48) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=97.0 ms
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=94.9 ms
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=3 ttl=51 time=94.6 ms
64 bytes from li63-48.members.linode.com (97.107.133.48): icmp_req=4 ttl=51 time=94.8 ms
```

I use `Google DNS`. Here is my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
search fornex.org
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Could anybody suggest, what's wrong with my server. Or verify that their is a problem with get.rvm.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linode are under big ddos attack in the last days.. you can here more details: http://status.linode.com/

> Identified - We have detected a distributed DoS attack affecting the
>   Linode Manager/Website/API and are working with our upstream provider
>   to mitigate it. We will continue to keep this post updated with
>   further information.

---

> We've detected a large DoS attack targeting our London datacenter and
>   are working with our upstream provider to mitigate the attack. Users
>   will likely experience packet loss and problems with connectivity to
>   Linodes in London.

---

> Identified - The DoS attack in Newark appears to have returned and we
>   are working with our upstream provider to mitigate it at this time. As
>   before, some users may run into packet loss or problems with
>   connectivity to Linodes in Newark.  Dec 31, 13:50 UTC Monitoring - At
>   this time we believe the DoS attack has been mitigated and users
>   should not be experiencing connectivity issues. However, we are still
>   monitoring for additional attacks in Newark.  Dec 31, 13:39 UTC
>   Identified - We've identified a large DoS attack targeting our
>   infrastructure in our Newark datacenter. We're working with our
>   upstream provider to mitigate the attack, however, some users may
>   still encounter packet loss and problems with connectivity to Linodes
>   in Newark.